# Hashes of the same string do not match for Changing Password feature

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt

I am developing a NodeJS, ReactJS based web application in which I want to give the user provision to change their passwords. Here's the code for the route:

```
router.put('/changepass/:user_id', auth, async (req, res) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()});
    }

    const {oldPassword, newPassword} = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.user_id);

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); //10 rounds

        const prevPassword = await bcrypt.hash(oldPassword, salt);

        if(prevPassword !== user.password) {
            return res.status(400).send({errors: [{msg: 'Old password does not match'}]});
        }

        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);

        await user.save();

    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
})
```

The problem is, the **prevPassword** hash does not match the hash of the already stored User password, even though the password strings are the same. Why am I getting 2 different hashes for the same password string?

Comment: You're generating the hash with a new salt. Obviously it won't match the original hash generated with the original salt.

Comment: Oh now I get it. I should use the same salt for both register and changepassword routes!

Comment: Now I am facing another problem, If I generate the salt outside the routes, so all routes utilize the same salt like this:
`const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);`
Then I get this error _Illegal arguments: string, object_
when this runs:
`const prevPassword = await bcrypt.hash(oldPassword, salt);`

Comment: *Don't use the same salt for all passwords.* Firstly, that defeats the purpose of having a salt, and secondly the moment you restart the server all logins break because it generates a new salt. When checking the old password use the salt stored in the database.

Comment: How do I check the stored salt?